# How do I compute the full derivative of a function in general from (that is in turn is a function of a function) in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

How do I compute a function that is a function of a function, written in general form in mathematica? Say I want to compute the full derivative of the following equation w.r.t alpha (or a in my case):

[image]

I have tried

```
v (a_) := u (x (a), a)

D[v (a), a]
```

But this gives the wrong output (out = v).

Desired output (nevermind the blue arrow):

[image]

Comment: Use brackets not parenthesis for function definitions and calls.

Comment: Thanks. So v[a_] := u[x[a], a] and D[v[a], a]  ? Something still seems wrong..

Comment: That should be fine. Read the documentation for `Derivative`.